# How to check id-s of parents and then set value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table like this :

```
ID  object_id    parent_id   allowed
1       1           0           0   
2       23          25          1
3       25          44          0       
4       44          38          0       
5       38          1           0
6       52          55          1           
7       55          58          0
8       58          60          0
9       60          1           0
```

Now want select row-s where allowed = 1 and then  set allowed = 1 for parents of the row which i select. For example it will be like :

step 1. `select object_id , parent_id from myTbl where allowed = 1` Displays:

```
ID  object_id    parent_id   allowed
2       23          25          1   
6       52          55          1
```

step 2: It checks if the `object_id` is `IN` the `parent_id` from the above result and  sets `allowed = 1` when the object_id is equal to any of the parent_id's.

The exact same step2 repeats until it reaches a point where there is no match between `object_id` and `parent_id`

```
ID  object_id    parent_id   allowed
2       23          25          1   
6       52          55          1
3       25          44          0 --update to 1
7       55          58          0 -- update to 1
```

The exact same principle is being applied to the folling records, too:

for 25,44,1 - 44,38,0 (allowed is 0  want set 1) when set allowed = 1 it will be 
44,38,1

for 55,58,1 - 58,60,0 (allowed is 0  want set 1) when set allowed = 1 it will be 
58,60,1

How to do it ? In table My table contains multiple records with status `allowed=1` and only 2 of them are used in this particular example.

Comment: Have try to fix it by using CTE (Common Table Expression)?

Comment: If the update goes on and on would it not update all records and therefore all records will eventually becomes `allowed = 1`?

Comment: @Edper: Thats not necessarily true, because the `UPDATE` will continue until it reaches a point where: `object_id not in (Select parent_id from tbl)`. However, if the every `parent_id` contains a set of `objects`, then you are completely right and there is no need of the `allowed flag`

Comment: @Kiril But it looks like all the `parent_id` has a matching `object_id` except of course `object_id = 1`. I think the `allowed` flag is only useful in interim but eventually become un-useful (not necessarily useless).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET    allowed = 1 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   tbl 
        WHERE  allowed = 0) A 
        INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT * 
            FROM   tbl                 
            WHERE  allowed = 1) B 
        ON A.objectid = B.parentid
```

Comment: this query set allowed = 1 to all data in table

Comment: @GeoVIP: That means all of your objects are contained into the parent_ids.. and I can't find a reason for using that flag.

Comment: @GeoVIP: Yes, because all your `parent_ids` have a match on one of the `object_id` except for the one whose `object_id=1` or `parent_id=0` which is the root of the hierarchy here.