# How to select data from CTE for where clause in another select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Have CTE like :

```
WITH atree as(SELECT [sort],[object_id],[object_type],[parent_id],[allowed],1 [lvl]
FROM @tbl 
WHERE [object_id] in (select object_id from @tbl where allowed = 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT tb.sort , tb.[object_id],tb.[object_type],tb.[parent_id],tb.[allowed], [lvl] + 1 [lvl]
FROM @tbl tb 
INNER JOIN atree at ON at.[parent_serno] = tb.[object_serno])
```

Now want update table like :

```
UPDATE @tbl 
SET allowed = 1 where sort in (select distinct sort from atree)
```

but have an error while update. How to write correct update for CTE ?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to update the table? Do you want to run the update every time any row is added, changed or removed? If you don't, then the `allowed` column will be immediately up to date. If you can identify the rows that should be `allowed = 1` in a query, why not just always calculate it that way? Then it's never out of date.

Comment: Yes I want update every time when row changed or remove , because i split data from xml and then insert into tbl, and this data will always different

Comment: Isn't that related to: [check parents and set value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399200/how-to-check-id-s-of-parents-and-then-set-value)

Comment: What error exactly you are getting?